# What is the distinction between a Set, a Category, and a Class?

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to wrap my head around terminology of Category theory but I can't wrap my mind around the distinction between a Set, a Category, and a Class.

I want to be very specific but it feels like each source I read is inconsistent in some way.

Can somebody please explain?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: What do you mean by "Set", "Category", "Class"? Category of sets, of categories, of classes, respectively, or something different?

Comment: I have no idea. The specific terms. Are they really that context sensitive?

Comment: Also, have you tried to read Mac Lane's "Categories for the working mathematician" (it is the most common handbook on category theory) or at least the Wikipedia's [definition of category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)#Definition)?

Comment: I have, I actually went to my school library and got it. I tried reading it for 2 weeks. I couldn't make much sense of it. I really tried to follow it but it seemed to avoid being very specific about the terms, I would follow it for a bit then all  the suddenly it would skip many details and assume you already know something that you don't. It was a discouraging experience.

Comment: Okay...If you speak russian (or not), you can contact me by e-mail (oskar808@mail.ru), and I will try to explane some basic things to you. Your question is too vague for MSE, I guess...

Comment: Well, in my statistics class, my professor uses Sets, Classes, Categories equivalently. Once I start changing my mindset to understand Category Theory, I get overwhelmed.

Comment: Your stats professor isn't talking about categories in the sense of MacLane, then-they're just uses the word in its colloquial sense, namely, "collection."

Comment: @Oskar It's funny that I didn't check before on wikipedia, and that they simply say a category is a *class* of objects, ... and so on...